# Problem with width in percentage in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have problem with width using percentage in Mozilla Firefox.

In Firefox:
[image]

In Opera:
[image]

#### Code

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <meta name="author" content="adminite">

    <title>Untitled 2</title>
    <style>
    #cont {
    width:99.8%;
    height:125px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:#1ea1de;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="cont">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility is that you haven't reseted the browser default styles.

Try:

```
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

If that's the case, you might benefit from using a reset stylesheet such as this one:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/